# Countably compactness , 1st Countability and homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

> Let (X,T) be a countably compact space, let (Y,U) be a first countable space and let $f: X \to Y$ be a continuous bijection. Prove that f is  a homeomorphism.

The given statements in the question already tells that f is bijective and continuous and I have to prove that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Let O be an open set in Y. Let $o_i$ be elements of O then $f^{-1}(o_i) =x_i$ because f is bijective. But I am unable to think how to prove $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Can you please help with that?

Comment: You might need that $Y$ is Hausdorff? Otherwise $X=[0,1]$ (standard) $Y=[0,1]$ (indiscrete), $f(x)=x$ is a counterexample.

Comment: What text is this from?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Worksheets given by instructor.

Comment: So he overlooked this requirement. Sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: show that $f$ is a closed map (which is equivalent to $f^{-1}$ being continuous for a bijection).

You'll need that $Y$ is Hausdorff (or something close to it) too. See my example in the comments.
If $C$ is closed in $X$ what can you say about $f[C]$? What happens if it were *not* closed? hint2: sequences...